# image clickable in a expandiblelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i have a imagen in the right of groups of expandiblelistview.
I want that when i click in the image, this expand de group, but when i click in the image this doit nothing.

I have this code in my onCreate, i dont know if this must to be in de expandible list adapter.

```
    /*****************************************************************/
// Elementos del layout
        expLista = getExpandableListView();
        expLista.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        expLista.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                grupoCLickeado = groupPosition;
                ImageView btnExpandir = (ImageView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgExpandir);
                btnExpandir.setFocusable(false);
                btnExpandir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        expLista.expandGroup(grupoCLickeado, true);
                    }
                });
                expLista.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                        expLista.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        codigoServicio = numerosServicios.get(groupPosition);
                    }

                });

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think the problem is bcoz you are using collapse group inside your  setOnGroupExpandListener. Why do u do that on every expand?

Comment: I again Andro ;). I want when user click in the image, this expand de group, but when click outside de image, but inside of row do nothing..is it possible?

Comment: Yeah it is possible. Please wait. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **OnGroupExpandListener** you have to use **setOnGroupClickListener**,

Instead of this,

```
expLista.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    expLista.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    codigoServicio = numerosServicios.get(groupPosition);
                }

            });
```

Use this,

```
expLista.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {

                        expLista.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: did u remove setOnGroupExpandListener and check?

Comment: Yes i do, but with this code, when i click in a image, expand me the last group what i clicked, but not the inmediatly i was click.

Comment: There are any way to detect de row that i clicked when i click in a imageview inside this row??